# DNS entries for rack controller

Tags: dns, maas

I have a rack controller with 5 interfaces which are automatically picked up by maas, i.e. creating fabrics and subnets etc. I want MAAS to handle only two of these subnets so I set all the other subnets to "unmanaged". However it seems that this does not affect DNS behavior. When I try to ping the rack controller from a node in my network it retrieves to a local ip of an unmanaged subnet. Is there a way to specify which subnet to prefer? Ultimately I don't want MAAS to care about any of the other subnets.

Answer (score 0):

The maas chat was helpful and this is the solution they came up with:

`maas admin dnsresources create fqdn=hostname.maas ip_addresses=<ip>`

Alternatively they suggested putting the maas service inside a container and only expose the interfaces you need.